# Are user folders really by default not available to administrator(s) in Windows 10 Pro?

Tags: windows-10, permissions, administrator, user-folders

I've set up a Win 10 Pro system with an administrator account (A) and some standard user accounts (B-D). When I try to access as user A the /users/userB/ folder, for example, I get a message saying that I don't have the appropriate rights to view that folder, and there is a question box asking me to select Continue if I want to permanently get the rights.

Is this really the default behaviour of Win 10 or have I somehow messed up in setting up the system? I haven't set a up system with other users for quite some time, so cannot really remember.

Comment: This appears to be the default behavior of Windows 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows 10 USER folders are very secure. So in default operation, a local Administrator cannot see another user's data and this is the default setup.

If the Administrator wishes to take ownership of the folder, they can take ownership.  That was the question you saw "Continue if I want to permanently get the rights".

So what you see is quite normal.

Comment: Great to hear, thank you!

Comment: +1 from me. @kissel if you no longer need help, can you press the check mark besides the answer? That way others know you no longer need help.

Comment: Yes, sorry I'm new here. :)